# Service worker update only changed content in cache, or share data between service workers

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have following service worker:

```
var files2cache = {
    "001.html": 1482843787, 
    ..
    "/": 1482821117, 
};

self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
            return cache.addAll(Object.keys(files2cache));
        })
    );
});

// If request matches something in cache - return it from cache
// otherwise do actual request
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
            return response || fetch(event.request);
        })
    );
});
```

`files2cache` is generated and contains timestamps of last changes done to files listed in it.

The question is how to get value of this variable from previous version of  service worker, so I could `addAll` only files for which `files2cache[fn] > oldFiles2cache[fn]` is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are (at least) two options for storing this versioning information:

**Modify the URLs Used as Keys in the Cache Storage API**

This is the approach that [`sw-precache` uses](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache). It modifies request URLs to append a new URL query parameter of the form `_sw-precache=<ID>` before storing entries using the Cache Storage API. You can see this in action by looking at Chrome's cache viewer after visiting the [demo page](https://googlechrome.github.io/sw-precache/):

[image: sw-precache parameter]

Since your `fetch` handler needs to perform cache matching against URLs that don't include this additional query parameter, you need to modify the URL that you match against to add in the expected versioning information prior to calling `caches.match()`. `sw-precache` handles this by [maintaining a mapping](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/blob/master/service-worker.tmpl#L52) of original URL to the URL with versioning information.

**Use IndexedDB to Store Versioning Information**

There's a little more overhead involved in this approach, as you need to synchronize information in both IndexedDB and the Cache Storage API, but by offloading versioning information to IndexedDB, you keep the cached request URLs unmodified, which makes it easier to perform cache lookups using `caches.match()` against "real" URLs.

There's an [example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-helpers/blob/master/packages/sw-precaching/src/lib/models/revision-details-model.js) of this approach in the new `sw-precaching` project in the `sw-helpers` repo. The project is still a work in progress, but it should illustrate the concepts.

Using a IndexedDB wrapper library that supports promises, like https://www.npmjs.com/package/idb-keyval, can really simplify things if you take this approach.